# How to select <script> tag in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

It's not necessary, but i have tried to select `<script>` tag in css. But it didn't work. Why ?

```
<style>
    script {
        padding:80px;
        background-color:red;
    }
</style>
```

This should work. Because it works on other elements. But not on script tag .

```
<script>alert(1)</script>
```

And this is the tag i want to  select.

Comment: You don't style `<script>` tags. Those are used for JavaScript.

Comment: script - by default - is set to display:none;. Why are you doing this? If it is to display some of your code then use other html elements i.e. pre, code etc

Comment: Who upvoted this question ?

Comment: I upvoted this question as it shows research effort, IMHO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to set `display` property:

```css
 script{
 display:block;
 padding:80px;
 background-color:red;
 }
```

```html
<script>console.log(1)</script>
```

Comment: @Rob, what do you mean by emulator? Are you suggesting that SO doesn't use your browser to display code when you use a code snippet?

Comment: @Rob that's not an emulator. Code snippets runs on your browser, according to your browser rules. Watch SO on IE and some snippets will work different than on Chrome, just like in the "real world"

Comment: how can i display single <script> only

Comment: like #id script{ }

Comment: like `#id {...}`

Comment: why the earth people want to style a script block? I don't understand at all.

Answer (score 4):

You can use display:block to show elements that normally wouldn't.

Browsers simply apply the following rule to hide unnecessary tags

```
head, title, link, meta, style, script {
    display: none;
}
```

But you can override it just like any other CSS. It even works on elements that are not even on the body, but the head, such as titles, metas, etc

```
head, title, link[href][rel], meta, style, script {
    display: block;
}
```

And even use some pseudo-elements magic to show attributes of tags such as the rel for your CSS link tag, or the content for your description

```css
title, link[href][rel], meta, style, script {
 display: block;
}

link[href][rel]::after {
  content: attr(rel) ': ' attr(href);
 text-transform: capitalize;
}

meta[charset]::after {
 content: 'Charset: ' attr(charset);
}

meta[name][content]::after {
 content: attr(name) ': ' attr(content);
 text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>This is the title</title>
  <meta name="description" content="This is the Description">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

</head>

<body>
  <script>/*This is inside an script tag*/</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And then you can style them as you would any regular html element.

Does this have any practical purpose? Nope, none at all. Maybe (and stretching it quite a bit) displaying the title on a print stylesheet. 
Other than that, it's just a pointless *fun fact*.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The answers posted here are sufficient, but for fun I decided to mess around with this. I noticed a few things. This code makes a short JavaScript visible, and executes it.

```css
body {
    background-color:#2a4128;
    color:white;
    font-size:1.05em;
}
 
script {
    display:block;
    color:#ef9a9a;
    background-color:#321117;
    font-weight:normal;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid red;
    font-family:"Courier New";
    font-size:0.94em;
    text-align:left;
}
.script-area {
    text-align:center;
    width:79%;
    margin-left:10%;
    margin-right:10%;
}
h2 { color:pink; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
   <title>Testing</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Hello world!</h3>
        <p>Let's see how this script works!!!</p>
        <div class="script-area">
            <pre><script type="text/javascript">
document.write("<p>This script came from a visible element!</p>");
document.getElementsByTagName("h3")[0].innerHTML = "I changed this with <b><i>inline JavaScript!</i></b>";
console.log(1);
            </script></pre>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Like others have stated, the web browser automatically hides typically invisible elements - not just `<script>`, but `<meta>`, `<title>`, `<style>`, and so on. This is done with the `display:none;` CSS directive. Like any CSS rule, this can be overwritten with your own. Just select the `script` and use `display:block;`.

The script that is now visible on the page, is executed like it normally is. I've noticed the script is unaware of elements that appear after it, and only aware of the DOM that appears before it. I initially placed the brief script in the `<head>` tag, but I was unable to make it visible with CSS. This is probably due to some kind of

```
head { display:none; }
```

rule in the browser software. But I imagine this can be overruled just like for the `<script>`.